# SSRS expression not working properly while using formatcurrency function

Tags: reporting-services

I have small expression on value fields in SSRS report. Source data type of value is `NVARCHAR`. It has some numeric value as well which I want to convert into currency and else should be display as it is.

```
=IIF(Fields!Description.Value LIKE "Blank*","",
    IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!Value.Value)=True,FormatCurrency(Fields!Value.Value,0),Fields!Value.Value)
    )
```

Report displays the numeric values in currency format but where it has string values it showing `#Error`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use LIKE in an SSRS expression.. you need to use something like this:

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!Description.Value,"Blank")>0,"",
    IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!Value.Value)=True,FormatCurrency(Fields!Value.Value,0),Fields!Value.Value)
    )
```

Comment: Actually, as there is no wildcard at the start you could simply do `IIF(LEFT(Fields!Description.Value,5) = "Blank", True_bit_here, False_bit_here)`